# Extjs. Close popup window by click not in window

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have popup window, not modal.
How can I close this window by click on other part of page (not in window)?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
function closeWin(e, t) {
    var el = win.getEl();

    if (!(el.dom === t || el.contains(t))) {
        Ext.getBody().un('click', closeWin);
        win.close();
    }
}

Ext.getBody().on('click', closeWin);
```

Comment: Greate! Thank you.Tell me please how can I unregister this click event?

Comment: I noticed that this method of identifying clicks outside of the window doesn't deal well when the window contains a combobox, because the combo's dropdown list seems not to be rendered as a child of the window. Clicking on the dropdown list to choose an item then is interpreted as a click outside of the window.  What's a straightforward way to recognize the list as a part of the window here?  http://jsfiddle.net/FScHR/4/

Comment: update with options fix: var el = cmp.getEl();
        // Fix for combo box option.
        if (!(el.dom === t || el.contains(t) || ('option' === t.getAttribute('role')))) {
            Ext.getBody().un('click', cmp.closeWin);
            cmp.close();
        }